# How do I use command substition in Dockerfile

Tags: dockerfile, command-substitution

In my Dockerfile I need to use command substition to add some environment variables. I want to set

```
ENV PYTHONPATH /usr/local/$(python3 -c 'from distutils import sysconfig; print(sysconfig.get_python_lib())')
```

but it doesn't work. The result is

```
foo@bar:~$ echo $PYTHONPATH
/usr/local/$(python3 -c from distutils import sysconfig; print(sysconfig.get_python_lib()))
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### What went wrong

The `$( ... )` [command substitution](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html) you attempted is for Bash, whereas the Dockerfile is not Bash. So docker doesn't know what to do with that, it's just plain text to docker, docker just spews out what you wrote as-is.

### Recommendation

To avoid hard-coding values into a Dockerfile, and instead, to dynamically change a setting or custom variable as `PYTHONPATH` during the build,  perhaps the `ARG ...` , `--build-arg` docker features might be most helpful, in combination with `ENV ...` to ensure it persists.

Within your Dockerfile:

```
ARG PYTHON_PATH_ARG

ENV PYTHONPATH ${PYTHON_PATH_ARG}
```

In Bash where you build your container:

```bash
python_path="/usr/local$(python3 -c 'from distutils import sysconfig; print(sysconfig.get_python_lib())')"

docker build --build-arg PYTHON_PATH_ARG=$python_path .
```

### Explanation

According to documentation, [`ARG`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#arg):

> The `ARG` instruction defines a variable that users can pass at build-time to the builder with the docker build command using the `--build-arg <varname>=<value>` flag.

So, in Bash we first:

```
python_path="/usr/local$(python3 -c 'from distutils import sysconfig; print(sysconfig.get_python_lib())')"
```

- `$(...)` Bash command substitution is used to dynamically put together a Python path value
- this value is stored temporarily in a Bash variable `$python_path` for clarity

```
docker build --build-arg PYTHON_PATH_ARG=$python_path .
```

- Bash variable `$python_path` value is passed to docker's `--build-arg PYTHON_PATH_ARG`

Within the Dockerfile:

```
ARG PYTHON_PATH_ARG
```

- so `PYTHON_PATH_ARG` stores the value from `--build-arg PYTHON_PATH_ARG...`

`ARG` variables are not equivalent to `ENV` variables, so we couldn't merely do `ARG PYTHONPATH` and be done with it.  According to documentation about [Using arg variables](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#using-arg-variables):

> `ARG` variables are not persisted into the built image as `ENV` variables are.

So finally:

```
ENV PYTHONPATH ${PYTHON_PATH_ARG}
```

- We use Dockerfile's `${...}` convention to get the value of `PYTHON_PATH_ARG`, and save it to your originally named `PYTHONPATH` environment variable

### Differences from original code

You originally wrote:

```
ENV PYTHONPATH /usr/local/$(python3 -c 'from distutils import sysconfig; print(sysconfig.get_python_lib())')
```

I re-wrote the Python path finding portion as a Bash command, and tested on my machine:

```bash
$ python_path="/usr/local/$(python3 -c 'from distutils import sysconfig; print(sysconfig.get_python_lib())')"

$ echo $python_path
/usr/local//usr/lib/python3/dist-packages
```

Notice there is a double forward slash `... local//usr ...` , not sure if that will break anything for you, depends on how you use it in your code.

Instead, I changed it to:

```bash
$ python_path="/usr/local$(python3 -c 'from distutils import sysconfig; print(sysconfig.get_python_lib())')"
```

Result:

```
$ echo $python_path
/usr/local/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages
```

So this new code will have no double forward slashes.

Answer (score 3):

You should use `ARG` if possible. But sometimes you really need to use command substitution for a dynamic variable. As long as you put all the commands in the same `RUN` statement, then you can still access the value.

```
RUN foo=$(date) && \
    echo $foo
```